# Tensors and change of basis

Tags: tensor-calculus

When we say that a tensor is an array of numbers that transform according to some formula from one basis to another, can both bases be of the same coordinate system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for sure.

Indeed for 1 rank tensor we have that $A^{i} = \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{\prime j} } A^{\prime j} $.

Even looking at this formula we can say that there is no such constrains on coordinates system, as you assumed. Problem occur when you have non-differentiable functions (derivative does not exist ...)

Answer (score 0):

> *When we say that a tensor is an array of numbers that transform according to some formula from one basis to another, can both bases be of the same coordinate system?*

Nobody says that. You are making confusion between a tensor and its representations onto some bases.

Given $V$ as a vector space and $V^* $ as its dual, a tensor of type $(r,s)$ is, by definition, any multilinear map
$$
\tau\colon V^r\times{V^*}^s\to \mathbb{F}
$$
$\mathbb{F}$ being any field. Chosen a basis $\left\{\textbf{e}_i\right\} \in V$ and its corresponding dual $\left\{\alpha^j\right\} \in V^*$ such that $\alpha^j(\textbf{e}_i)=\delta^j_i$ the components of the tensor with respect to these bases are the values of the multilinear map $\tau$ evaluated thereupon. Standard matrix multiplication rules for components follows by distributivity of the product and the rules for the change of basis.

As an example for $(r,s)=(1,1)$ we have
$$
\tau\colon V\times V^*\to\mathbb{R}
$$
with $\tau_i^j=\tau(\textbf{e}_i,\alpha^j)$. Given a change of basis as orthogonal matrix $O$ we have
$$
\tau'(\textbf{e}_i',\alpha'^j)=\tau(O_i^k\textbf{e}_k,\,{O^{-1}}^j_r\alpha^r)=
O_i^k\,{O^{-1}}^j_r\,\tau_k^r
$$
which terminates the proof. As you see, should you choose the same basis, the transformation matrix will reduce to the identity.

Comment: "Nobody says that." Sadly, you would be surprised. "A tensor is a thing that transforms like a tensor" is disturbingly common.